# Online photo book service that allows downloading books as PDF

Tags: pdf

I am looking for an online photo book service that:

- can print a user created photo book on an actual paper book (i.e. not electronic)
- allows downloading books as PDF (unlike [Picaboo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picaboo)) without any visual watermark (unlike [Shutterfly](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shutterfly)).

Comment: If such a service would offer such a PDF, then they would remove the "vendor lock-in": you'd be able to use any other printing service to reproduce a physical book.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie they could make the PDF available for a fee.

Comment: Seems a bit overkill, but Lightroom (http://www.adobepress.com/articles/article.asp?p=1930508&seqNum=5) can do that

Comment: @VicAche newest Lightroom CC can't do photobooks anymore

Answer (score 1):

I think [Canva](https://www.canva.com/) allows for this. You can create all kinds of documents, and [photo books](https://www.canva.com/create/photo-books/) is one of them. They are not a print service, so you cannot actually print it there, but it seems like you are *not* looking for that. Photo books can be downloaded at the click of a button, in PDF and multiple other formats, with no watermark.